# How do you escape this regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm looking for

> "House M.D." (2004)

with anything after it. I've tried   `where id~'"House M\.D\." \(2004\).*';` and there's no matches

This works `id~'.*House M.D..*2004.*';` but is a little slow.

Comment: You should really include the PostgreSQL version in any questions. This is quite version specific.

Comment: @CraigRinger sorry for being slow but how do I find that?

Comment: `SELECT version();`. It's also printed every time you start `psql`, is shown in PgAdmin-III, is shown in package lists / installed program lists, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're on an older PostgreSQL version that interprets strings in a non standards-compliant C-escape-like mode by default, so the backslashes are being treated as escapes and consumed. Try `SET standard_conforming_strings = 'on';`.

As per the [lexical structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) documentation on string constants, you can either:

- Ensure that `standard_conforming_strings` is on, in which case you must double any single quotes (ie `'` becomes `''`) but backslashes aren't treated as escapes:

  `id ~ '"House M\.D\." \(2004\)'`
- Use the non-standard, PostgreSQL-specific `E''` syntax and double your backslashes:

  `id ~ E'"House M\\.D\\." \\(2004\\)'`

PostgreSQL versions 9.1 and above set `standard_conforming_strings` to `on` by default; see [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS).

You should turn it on in older versions after testing your code, because it'll make updating later much easier. You can turn it on globally in `postgresql.conf`, on a per-user level with `ALTER ROLE ... SET`, on a per-database level with `ALTER DATABASE ... SET` or on a session level with `SET standard_conforming_strings = on`. Use `SET LOCAL` to set it within a transaction scope.

Answer (score 2):

Looks that your regexp is ok

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/113

Comment: Yep, that's what I was saying in my answer. Just pointing out that the issue isn't the regexp, it's that the OP is using Pg 9.0 or older without `standard_conforming_strings` and didn't allow for backslashes being consumed by string literal parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.regexp_quote(IN TEXT) 
  RETURNS TEXT 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
  STABLE 
AS $$ 
/******************************************************************************* 
 * Function Name: regexp_quote 
 * In-coming Param: 
 *   The string to decoded and convert into a set of text arrays. 
 * Returns: 
 *   This function produces a TEXT that can be used as a regular expression 
 *   pattern that would match the input as if it were a literal pattern. 
 * Description: 
 *   Takes in a TEXT in and escapes all of the necessary characters so that 
 *   the output can be used as a regular expression to match the input as if 
 *   it were a literal pattern. 
 ******************************************************************************/ 
BEGIN 
  RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE($1, '([[\\](){}.+*^$|\\\\?-])', '\\\\\\1', 'g'); 
END; 
$$
```

Test:

```
SELECT regexp_quote('"House M.D." (2004)'); -- produces: "House M\\.D\\." \\(2004\\)
```